# How to join two table in Grocery CRUD Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, grocery-crud

How to Join the Two table in grocery CRUD? I have two tables - student activities and student profile. I wish to join the two tables in a single view (all columns).

Table structure:

**student_activity**

```
| id(PK) | stud_id(FK) | stud_achievement | stud_interest | stud_totalcgpa |
|stud_address | st‌​ud_grade | parent_name | parent_residence|
```

**student_profile**

```
| stud_id(PK) | stud_name | stud_class | stud_mobile | password | stud_email |
| login_datetime | logou‌​t_datetime | last_accessed |
```

I get the custom model code from this [website](http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=89)

**My controller Code :**

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$crud->set_model('Users_join'); 
$crud->set_table('student_profile','student_activity'); 
$crud->set_subject('Student'); 
$crud->columns('stud_id','stud_name','stud_class','stud_mobile','stud_email','st‌ud_achievement','stud_totalcgpa'); 
$crud->unset_operations(); 
$output = $crud->render(); 
$this->_example_output($output);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried already? Where's your database schema? Help us to help you

Comment: Edited the question with  Database schema. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AndyHolmes, Give some idea to join this two table in grocery CRUD codeigniter

Comment: I refer back to "what have you tried already?" and post the code of what you're already tried and where the errors are

Comment: @AndyHolmes , I get the custom model code from this [link](http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/264-join-tables/), and my controller code is `  $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
     $crud->set_model('Users_join');
     $crud->set_table('student_profile','student_activity');
     $crud->set_subject('Student');
  $crud->columns('stud_id','stud_name','stud_class','stud_mobile','stud_email','stud_achievement','stud_totalcgpa');
 $crud->unset_add();
  $output = $crud->render();
  $this->_example_output($output);` Output:it display only student_profile table column only remaining column or empty field

Comment: add the code to the question, not as a comment as it's difficult to read/understand and format it properly

Comment: @AndyHolmes, I'm add the code in question.